# Go next only if Android studio

Tags: android, if-statement

I have this code:

```
spinRoullete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (something) { check errors.}
                    if (something){something else}
```

If some errors exists stay there and show errors
If errors doesn't exist go forward to next if ..
And the errors

```
public void Errors () {
                    if (Rone.isChecked()) {
            if (nr1.getText().length() == 0) {
                nr1.setError("");
                nr1.requestFocus();
            } else {
                nr1.setError(null);
            }
        }           if (Rtwo.isChecked()) {
            if (nr1.getText().length() == 0) {
                nr1.setError("");
                nr1.requestFocus();
            } else {
                nr1.setError(null);
            }
            if (nr2.getText().length() == 0) {
                nr2.setError("");
                nr2.requestFocus();
            } else {
                nr2.setError(null);
            }
        }   
}
```

How can I make that? I'm new in this..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return;` to exit the method anywhere, so if you make your method checkErrors() to return a boolean, you can do this:

```
spinRoullete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (something) {
            if (check errors) {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (something) {
            something else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure your errors method returns boolean instead of void and write if (errors()) {

Comment: It's not working .. something it's wrong ..                                                        if (errors()){
                    return;
                } if (something) { }
This it's what I edited ..